Error updating message status displayed when clicking a link in inbox
I'd noticed this a couple days ago, but only been on mobile so getting a screenshot was hard (timing of tapping and hitting the screenshot buttons). Finally got one, but the error reads:

An error occurred while updating the status of the notification. Please try again.

This happens whenever I tap a message which is marked as unread; no message is displayed if it's read. The message is not marked as read on mobile, but is on desktop. Marking a message unread and then clicking the link replicates the issue. The message appears before the next page is loaded, so it doesn't appear for long (sometimes less than a second). The error is not shown on the page the link takes you to.
I'm using Firefox 127.0.2 on Android 12. I also tested on my Steam Deck, running Firefox 127.0.2 (desktop), which displays the same error (the only difference in behaviour is the former doesn't mark the message read).
Screenshot on mobile showing the error.

I see the same error message with firefox 115 ESR, but even on desktop, the message is not marked as read.

The inbox is the buggiest thing on the entire site. There are so many long-standing issues, some of which are known to be unfixable, that I'm not even bothering to report inbox-related stuff anymore. Still, +1 for your question: I've been noticing the exact same error popup for the last week (Firefox on Windows 11).

Messages haven't been getting marked as read when clicked for years (this is nothing new), certain comments' timestamps display as the wrong color when the page is visited from an inbox message (but not when the same page is accessed from elsewhere), and (this is the unfixable one) the 'new badge' popup notification uses the shape from the current site you're on and not the one where you actually earned the badge.

None of these really affect anything though other than minor visual inconsistencies (although the messages not marking as read is annoying)

Here is the same popup in light mode: https://www.mediafire.com/view/rx4gde7mnu558i0/errormessage.png/file

The badge shape thing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233517/badge-symbol-in-notification-is-of-the-site-youre-on-not-where-badge-was-earne

The comment timestamp color using the wrong color (site theme instead of light gray): https://www.mediafire.com/file/n1ki13tjelbbgcd/commenttimestamps.mp4/file

Confirmed on a "proper" PC (also running Firefox 126.0.2, as I haven't updated the PC yet this morning) behaviour is the same; the error is present and the message is marked as read.

Seems like this error might have been resolved; I haven't seen it today.
